# Create model instance from child form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model that belongs to :city :state and :country.

A City model belongs to a State.

And a State model belongs to a Country.

when a user is signing up they should be able to choose a location (city state & country) or add one if it is not in the database.  The problem is, when adding the city and state, I want to be able to associate them with their state or country respectively.  What I have so far is this

In my User model

```
belongs_to  :state 
belongs_to  :city
belongs_to  :country     

def city_name
  city.try(:name)
end

def city_name=(name)
  self.city = City.find_or_create_by_name(name.titleize) if name.present?
end

def country_name
  country.try(:name)
end

def country_name=(name)
  self.country = Country.find_or_create_by_name(name.titleize) if name.present?
end

def state_name
  state.try(:name)
end

def state_name=(name)
  self.state = State.find_or_create_by_name(name.titleize) if name.present?
end
```

In my user/new form

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :your_city %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :city_name, data: {autocomplete_source: cities_path} %>
  <br /> or <%= link_to "add New Location" ,"javascript:toggleDiv('hideme');"%>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>

<div id="hideme">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :country_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :state_name %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Done this way I create and associate a user with a city state and country
but the city state and country are floating with no associations to their respective state and country parent.  Is there a way to associate these models on create of the user? should I abandon this approach?

Comment: Would it make more sense to have a User belong to a City, a City have many Users, a City belong to a State, a State have many Cities, a State belong to a Country, and a Country have many States? From what I understand, relationships have to go both ways. If something belongs_to something else, something else must have_one or have_many of something.

Comment: @BradRice that is how it is set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the place to do this would be in a `before_save` hook (or `before_create` if the City, State and Country never change).

Maybe something like this:

```ruby
class User < ActiverRecord::Base
  before_save :city_state_country_setup

  ...

  private

  def city_state_country_setup
    self.state.update_attributes(country_id: self.country.id)
    self.city.update_attributes(state_id: self.state.id)
  end
end
```

But I'll suggest you reconsider the structure of your data. You have redundant links that could lead to conflicts between your models. E.g. If you change the State of a User, but don't change the State of his or her City, then there will be a conflict between the User's State and the User's City's state.

One way around this is to have the User's State or Country be defined through the closer associations:

```
class User
  belongs_to  :city

  #New accessor methods for state and country
  def state
    @state ||= self.city.state
  end

  def state=(s)
     self.city.state = s
  end

  def country
    @country ||= self.state.country
  end

  def country=(c)
     self.state.country = c
  end

  ...

end
```

This way relationships between Users, Cities, States and Countries are each defined in only one place, which makes them less prone to conflicts. The only caveat with this approach is you'll have to make sure that when a User is created, that the City is created before you attempt to add the State, and the State before the Country. You can do this in your controller, or again in a `before_save` hook.